# Use Boost multi_index for combined keys

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

How can I use Boost multi_index to combine three keys into one query expression? Consider the following index structure:

```
struct indexItems {
    uint64_t x; // assume non-unique index
    std::string y; // assume unique within x
    std::string z; // assume unique within y
};
```

Let's say I want to query for items using binary AND operator: x=1 AND y="a" AND z="s". How can I do that?

All queries and inserts will use the combination of x+y+z to insert, update and delete items from the multi_index. Besides that I need to iterate over y and z sorted by x.

The examples I found so far only deal with single indices.

Comment: Do all your queries deal with x+y+z or are you looking for arbitrary combinations like x+z and y+z queries too?

Comment: Good question. I'll update the description.

Comment: When you say "I need to iterate over y and z sorted by x" does that mean you need to get all values with a specific y and then iterate over those values in order of x?  Or does that mean you want to iterate over all values sorted by x?

Comment: The latter. I never need to query for a specific y or z, but iterate over x and all associated y and z for that x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need multi_index_container for this.  You can do this:

```
inline bool operator<(const indexItems& l, const indexItems& r) {
    return std::tie(l.x, l.y, l.z) < std::tie(r.x, r.y, r.z);
}

inline bool operator==(const indexItems& l, const indexItems& r) {
    return std::tie(l.x, l.y, l.z) == std::tie(r.x, r.y, r.z);
}

std::set<indexItems> items; // or use map with any second type
```

Now you have a set of data ordered first by x, then by y, then by z.  To query for `x=1 AND y="a" AND z="s"`:

```
items.find(indexItems{1, "a", "s"});
```

To iterate over all values sorted by x (secondarily sorted by y and z, though that isn't actually required it doesn't hurt either):

```
for (const indexItems& item : items)
    // ...
```

As a bonus, if you want to find all values within some range of `x`:

```
auto it = items.lower_bound(indexItems{100});
auto end = items.upper_bound(indexItems{105});
for (; it != end; ++it)
    // ...
```

Comment: Very elegant. Thank you.